# Google Cloud Ops Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am having an issue where Google Cloud Ops Agent logging gathers a lot of data and fills up my entire debian server hard drive in about 3 weeks due to the ever increasing size of the log file.

I do not want to increase the size of my server hard drive.

Does anyone know how to configure Google Cloud Ops Agent so that it only retains log data for the previous 7 days ?

EDIT: Google Cloud Ops Agent log file is stored in directory below

**/var/log/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/logging-module.log**

Comment: Are you using any log-rotation solution? Are you sure its not your application? Could you check which files are the largest or you have hundreds of small files? Are you using any compression?

Comment: Google Cloud Ops Agent directory on the debian server contains a single log file that grows to gigabytes in size over a period of a few weeks. The single log file keeps growing in size and fills up the entire hard drive.

Comment: Could you provide more details how did you configure your OPS Agent? If I understand, logs are on your Debian VM. Are you using `logrotate` or any software to archive old logs or remove logs older than 7 days?

Comment: I did not configure ops agent. It was installed from the google cloud platform console with the click of a mouse button, so it would be the default configuration. No I am not using logrotate or archiving software. The google cloud opts agent log increases in size by about 350 MB per day

Comment: So those logs who filling your VM is not your application logs, but the file which takes whole space is `logging-module.log`? Honestly I agree with `guillaume blaquiere` answer that Cloud OPS Agent is sending logs to Cloud Logging and shouldn't generate so huge log files on your VM. Could you confirm if OPS Agent working properly as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#gce-ui-install)? From many apps you are getting those logs and which verbosity? It's only warning, error, info, etc.

Comment: Yes the single file logging-module.log located in the google-cloud-ops-agent directory increases by about 350 MB per day until eventually the entire server HDD is completely full.

Comment: Which OPS Agent version are you using? Could you provide output of `sudo systemctl status google-cloud-ops-agent"*"`? Also could you check if you dont have 403 spam like mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/troubleshooting#logging-module-logs) or authorization issue spam which can be fixed [using this guide](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/authorization)? Did you try to restart OPS Agent?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. There doesn't seem to much for resources out there on how to deal with it. I could set up a custom logrotate rule to deal with it, but it doesn't seem like it's my responsibility and depending on the internals of gcloud ops monitor could cause issues. That logging-module.log within /var/log/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/ consistency fills up until disk is at 95% usage.

Comment: Yes rebooting the operating system or restarting the google cloud ops agent does not resolve the issue. Systemctrl stats is reporting no issues and there are no issues recorded in the logs. Seems like google should be fixing this issue.

Comment: @MikeMoy which Cloud OPS Agent you are using? If I good remember there was issue with version 2.7.1. Currently you can install 2.8.0 and 2.8.1. Could you reinstall OPS agent to the newest 2.8.1 version to check if this issue still occurs by following [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation)

Comment: I have google cloud ops agent Version: 2.8.1~debian10

Comment: Permissions on the log file are -rw-r--r-- root root

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. What kind of application do you have on that Debian-Server?

Comment: @PjoterS thanks for all the help. It seems as though if you has an old version of google opts agent and upgraded at some point in time like myself that the flaw is not fixed unless you know to manually SSH into the server and delete the buffer chunks. Solution below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced the same issue recently while using agent 2.11.0. And it's not just an enormous log file, it's also a ridiculous CPU usage! Check it out in htop.
If you open the log file you'll see it spamming errors about buffer chunks. Apparently, they got broken smh, so the agent can't read them and send away. Thus, high IO and CPU usage.

The solution is to stop the service:

```
sudo service google-cloud-ops-agent stop
```

Then clear all buffer chunks:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/google-cloud-ops-agent/fluent-bit/buffers/
```

And delete log file if you want:

```
sudo rm -f /var/log/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/logging-module.log
```

Then start the agent:

```
sudo service google-cloud-ops-agent start
```

This helped me out.

Btw this issue is described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206159141) and it seems that Google "fixed" it since 2.7.0-1. Whatever they mean by it since we still faced it...

Comment: This is insane that google did not send a message out to all google cloud platform customers informing them of the flaw in google cloud opts agent. It seems as though if you had an old version of google opts agent and upgraded at some point in time like myself that the flaw is not fixed unless you know to manually SSH into the server and delete the buffer chunks. Very poorly handled from google, this must still be affecting many other google cloud platform users.

Comment: The log file now does not exceed 1kB, instead of previously filling up an entire server of GBs and yes you are correct my server CPU usage dropped by over 30% with the above fix for google cloud ops agent. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: which version helps fix this?